# retrieve source code create a mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I got a DB in MYSQL (that I haven't created), I do not have the code that was used for it.
I want to know what was the code used to create one of the tables in the DB , is there an option to do so? I need to create the same table but on diffrent data..

Thanks alot!
P

Comment: Have you tried `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename;` ?

Comment: Yes  it shows this:
CREATE TABLE `one` (
  `Column1` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Sample` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `Gender` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Filename` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Quality` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 ) ENGINE=InDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Which kind of "source code" are you looking for?

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL Workbench you can display the DDL for any DB object. Just right click on it in the schema tree on either `Copy to Clipboard` or `Send to SQL Editor` and `Create Statement`:

[image]

Comment: I want to know which fields from which other tables was used and what was the conditions for the new table

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what you mean.

Comment: I want to get the code that was used, for example:
'CREATE TABLE  originoneN10 
select * FROM one_origin 
WHERE CalcOrigin IN (SELECT *
                        FROM (SELECT CalcOrigin
                              FROM one_origin
                              GROUP BY CalcOrigin
                              HAVING COUNT(CalcOrigin) >= 10)
                        AS a) ;'

Comment: I think that's not stored by the server and hence cannot be retrieved. That `select` clause only serves as template at creation time. The referenced objects can change since the table was created and hence a stored template wouldn't make much sense.

Comment: Thanks, do you know if there an option to change the settings of the workbench so it would save it  in every new table I will create?

Answer (score 0):

This is a late answer, but since I don't see any reference to it, I'll suggest you to perform a **dump** of your database. Every decent DBMS has now a tool to do it. With MySQL, from command line, this would be :

```
mysqldump -u <username> <database_name> > yourfile.sql
```

This performs a complete dump in SQL format of your base, enabling you to recreate it elsewhere. No need for any special tool to do it when you need to. Just pass the content of the file to the regular MySQL's client.

If you want to get only the database schema without any data, just pass "**--no-data**" option.

```
mysqldump --no-data -u <username> <database_name> > yourfile.sql
```

You'll now be able to recreate a brand new, virgin database, having all attributes and special features of the previous one, without the data.